# TFS Git create repo - "User must become compliant"

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We're in the process of converting to TFS Git, however, every time I try to create a new repo from Visual Studio (that is, create a local repo, and sync it to Visual Studio Online), I get an error message:

"User '*@*.com' must become compliant. Compliance can be updated at: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/go/profile?mkt=en-US Compliance can be updated at: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/go/profile?mkt=en-US&cv=&cs=&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_apis%2FToken%2FSessionTokens"

Anybody ever experience a similar issue? I can pull repos created in VSO without any issues, and sync those back to VSO. The only issue is taking a local repo and pushing it to VSO.

---

As the OP hasn't updated with the requested steps, here's how this is happening for me:

- Create local git repo
- Do some stuff in it, and commit changes
- Click "sync" and get offered three "Publish to" options of "Visual Studio Online", "GitHub", or  "Remote Repository"
- Click "Get Started" under "Publish to Visual Studio Online"
- Log in with MS account
- Get the message referred to above and no option to do anything else with VSO

Navigating to either of the addresses in the error message (by hand - they aren't clickable within VS) takes me to the "My Information" page where I can update my name, email address, and country (and communications preferences), or create another free VSO account (to go with the one already listed).

**Note** getting the repo URL from VSO and entering that in the "Publish to Remote Repository" option seems to work OK, so it's easy to work around the problem; I'd just like to know why there is a problem in the first place (and how to solve it "properly")

Comment: Can you explain the steps you did to push this local repo. Because you have to create the repo in tfs, then add it as a remote then you can push...

Comment: TFS can't just automatically create the repo with the same name as the local repo, in the TFS project I'm already connected to? Being a consultant business, we'll be continuously creating new repos for each customer. Maybe we would be better off sticking to Team Foundation Version Control instead of Git?

Comment: Indeed, you have to create the repo from the website but don't get it wrong, stay with git, it's not a big deal, just a 2 minutes job.

Comment: I had the same problem and I just updated to VS 2015 SP1... This must be a bug. I use the same login for both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: I have encountered this problem today too when trying to populate a newly created VSTS project with an existing repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is technically correct (although horribly formatted, we'll fix that). Open an inprivate browser, type https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/go/profile?mkt=en-US and in the [authentication screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5M5E.jpg) select '**work or school account**'.

You'll see a screen similar to this: [Directory Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiZa6.png). 
What you want to do is *select a directory*. You might be asked to *create a profile*, please do so.

If/when you land on the [Profile Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20GlD.png) where in the directory picker at the top you want to select one by one every other directoroies you have listed (except Microsoft account) and create profiles if asked.

Everything should work after. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This may seem illogical to log in using incognito mode/inprivate browser, but it did reveal the problem on my account. By logging in normally, everything looked like it was configured correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In general: you need to create a profile and accept terms of service on the specified URL. Doing so makes you "compliant" to use Visual Studio Team Services.

Specifically for your case: The fact that navigating to that URL shows you your profile information as opposed to prompting you to create a profile indicates to me that most likely you are logged in with a different user identity in the browser than the user identity you are logged in to Visual Studio. Can you sign out of both Visual Studio (in the IDE top right corner) and Visual Studio Team Services (on your browser) and try again while making sure it's the same user identity for which you have already become "compliant"? I suspect that should fix the issue for you.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm logged in to Visual Studio and in my browser with the same account. As of now I used the publish option with the URL but I would like to get this resolved.

Comment: Shmuly, follow the steps in the "Albert Cabello MSFT" post. Even though it  takes you to the same page, it will present a different set of screens for you to confirm on your profile.